# Does MariaDB support data subscriptions?

Tags: mariadb

Every time I try Googling for this I end up looking at a "Pricing" page. Does anyone know if MariaDB offer subscriptions similar to [Postgres](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createsubscription.html)?

Comment: I think terminology for mariadb is master and salve

Comment: Well, the terminology is replication. Yes, mariadb supports replication.

Comment: Are either of those things subscriptions in the "realtime data" sense? Basically I want to create GraphQL subscriptions with a MariaDB database. Maybe I'm confusing terms. :(